# I have trouble understanding the flow of pipeline design pattern, especially how the chain of steps are executed one after the other?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I am trying to implement pipeline design pattern using reference from : https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/pipeline/ and https://medium.com/@deepakbapat/the-pipeline-design-pattern-in-java-831d9ce2fe21

I have created example classes as below to debug and understand the flow
.When the call  `jobPipeline.execute(12);` in `PipelineRunner.class` is fired, only first step's method should be executed correct? but how come other steps(second and third steps) are also getting executed one after the other?

**Step.class**

```
public interface Step<I, O> {
  O executeStep(I stepData);
}
```

**Pipeline.class**

```
public class Pipeline<I, O> {

  private final Step<I, O> current;

  public Pipeline(Step<I, O> current) {
    this.current = current;
  }

  public <K> Pipeline<I, K> next(Step<O, K> step) {
    return new Pipeline<>(input -> step.executeStep(current.executeStep(input)));
  }

  public O execute(I input) {
    return current.executeStep(input);
  }
}
```

**PipelineRunner.class**

```
public class PipelineRunner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Step<Integer, Integer> firstStep = x->{ System.out.println("First step");
      return 2; };

    Step<Integer, Integer> secondStep = x->{ System.out.println("Second step");
      return 2; };

    Step<Integer, Integer> thirdStep = x->{ System.out.println("Third step");
      return 2; };


    var jobPipeline = new Pipeline<>(firstStep)
        .next(secondStep)
        .next(thirdStep);


     jobPipeline.execute(12); //How rest of steps( second and third step) are executed with this single call on the jobPipeline object?

  }

}
```

**Ouput:**

```
First step
Second step
Third step
```

Comment: Step through the execution with the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
step.executeStep(current.executeStep(input))
```

`current.executeStep` is executed, and then `step.executeStep` so its result can be passed in.  This is no different from `Math.abs(1+2)` evaluating `1+2=3` before passing it to `Math.abs`.

Comment: I understand the logic of how one step input is being passed to other step but how and when the following steps are called in the process? .next(secondStep)  .next(thirdStep);

Comment: They're called when they appear in the code.  They build a new `Pipeline` object without executing it, and return it.